# Google Analytics API: tiny differences in results between GA API and Google Analytics UI

Tags: rest, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I'm querying **GA Report API v4** to get some metrics for AdWords Keywords.

As dimension I use:

```
ga:keyword
```

As metrics I use:

```
ga:adClicks,
ga:adCost,
ga:CPC,
ga:sessions,
ga:bounceRate,
ga:pageviewsPerSession,
ga:goalConversionRateAll,
ga:transactions,
ga:transactionRevenue
```

When I compare results pulled from API with results that I'm getting by Google Analytics UI, I found out that certain metrics in some Keywords has tiny differences.

Also when I tried **GA API v3** I had same result.

What is the reason?

Why some returned metrics for Keywords are fully identical to results in UI, but certain not?

I tried various date ranges: 1 day, week, month but in all cases I got some tiny differences in some metrics of certain Keywords.

Here is screenshot with example of differences in metrics how it looks like:[image]
In red color means the difference, green color - means that values are identical

Comment: Would your data be getting sampled? What metrics have differences?

Comment: Data returned from api are not sampled. I added screenshot with example of differences in metrics. In red color means the difference, green color - means that values are identical. Differences appear in random metrics except of  Clicks, Cost, CPC (always identical)

Comment: Where in the UI are you getting your results from? Are you getting them from the Acquisition>AdWords>Keywords report?

Comment: yes. Acquisition>AdWords>Keywords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:** The reason for the discrepancy is that you are calling two different reports.

Report 1) UI Report.

As you have seen, this report is made up of two parts the first being Clicks, Cost, and CPC which are from the Google AdWords API, and the other metrics (sessions, bounce, etc.) which is from Google Analytics.

Because you are going into AdWords > Keywords, you are actually setting a filter to select only AdWords traffic.

Report 2) Custom Report.

This report is pulling the keywords dimension without any filters. This means that the report will also have [data for organic keywords, and any UTM_term parameters set](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=traffic_sources&jump=ga_keyword).

Because sessions from organic keywords have no AdWords data, the first three columns will be the same, however the Google Analytics specific columns will show variation in the metrics.

**Solution:** 
To get your reports the same, you need to add a filter to your API request, such as `ga:adwordsCustomerID` or `ga:source=google & ga:medium=cpc`.